# Cannot add or update child row MySQL Error 1452

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-error-1452

I am getting this error:

> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`university`.`registration`, CONSTRAINT `registration_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`section_id`) REFERENCES `Section` (`section_id`))

---

This is my code

```
INSERT INTO Registration VALUES (24766, 1102, 'B', 'B');

CREATE TABLE Registration (
    student_id INT,
    section_id INT,
    midterm_grade VARCHAR(5),
    final_grade VARCHAR(5),
    PRIMARY KEY (student_id, section_id), 
    FOREIGN KEY (student_id) 
        REFERENCES Student (student_id), 
    FOREIGN KEY (section_id) 
        REFERENCES Section (section_id)
);
```

---

Any help would be appreciated on fixing this problem.

Comment: Make sure section table is created before you run `inserts` also do check section data with id 1102

Answer (score 2):

This is a common error in MySQL, most likey caused by either that `student_id` `24766` does not exist in the `Student` table, or `section_id` `1102` does not exist in the `Section` table.

The fix is to simply make sure that your foreign keys in the `Registration` table point to actual primary keys of records in the other two tables.  So, you may need to insert some data to resolve this error.